# Cómo ejecutar aplicaciones de escritorio de forma remota

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, raspberry-pi

me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cómo mandar ejecutar alguna aplicación de escritorio desde ssh.
El escenario es algo así: tengo una raspberry con raspbian conectada a una pantalla, quiero poder mandar abrir alguna aplicación, por ejemplo chrome en modo kiosko en una página especifica. Lo que quisiera hacer es controlar la sesión "actual" de forma remota. se podrá hacer con ssh o será necesario usar alguna aplicación de escritorio remoto como Remmina?
Busco cargar lo menos posible la memoria del dispositivo.

Comment: seteas la var `DISPLAY` para que tome la q esta activa ( por lo general es `:0` ) onda `export DISPLAY=:0 ; firefox -new-tab "www.duckduckgo.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Puedo usar VNC tambien y un túnel de SSH.  https://tecnotraffic.net/como-hacer-un-tunel-vnc-a-traves-de-ssh/

Comment: interesante, lo voy a revisar

Answer (score -1):

como menciona alo Malbarez con la variable

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

me funcionó

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/347826)

Comment: Agrega más detalles a tu respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._

Comment: Es muy bueno que estes por aquí, pero deberías de hacer un recorrido y leer: [como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), tambien puedes ver , [como dar un a buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) . Aquí hay más de 100 millones de visitas al mes. Preguntas y respuestas como la tuya, no ayudan micho. [La reputación la podra conseguir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) sin duda, pero no asi. A ti te ayudo, pero deberías explicar porque y como, ya que si otro usuario tiene el mismo problema, podrá encontrar solución.